# Paste the name of a column to a new column in a loop

Tags: r

I am trying to add 'ZS' to a column in a loop. I am able to add a new column number to the ZS but I want the original column it came from as well.

So far I have

```
Newdf<-df[, paste0('ZS' , 3:ncol(df))]
```

Isn't it possible to just do

```
Newdf<-df[, paste0('ZS' , 3:ncol(df),colname(df)]
```

Comment: Yes I want to add ZS to a column name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
names(df)[3:ncol(df)] <- paste0('ZS', names(df)[3:ncol(df)])
```